# How to match the string name to the file name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a information list which looks similar to this

```
List.txt
dir1, filename1, 1990/01/01, 1995/01/09 10:35, john
dir2, filename2, 1994/12/08, 1994/12/10 05:43, jenny
dir3, filename3, 2000/07/03, 2005/10/11 14:56, Henrik
```

The first is directory, filename, creation time, modification time, owner of the file.

This list is very long. During the migration from mainframe to Linux, all the directories and files were migrated safely and the contents inside of them are the same, BUT the problem is that the modification time is changed to the time when it was migrated, so all the files have the modification time of the year 2018.

So my task is to bring back the modification time of the files as it was before the migration. So for this I have to create a script which will look at the List.txt and match the directory name and file name inside of it with the files which are on Linux, and if they are same, it has to change the modification time to the old one.

This script I tried to change the modification time for newing.txt file to the List.txt and it worked..

```
#!/bin/bash

aa=$1
while IFS="," read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
do
        for n in $(pwd)
        do
                echo "$c1 $c2 $c3 $c4 $c5"

                y=$(echo $c4 | awk '{print $2}')
                b=$(echo $y | tr -d ':')
                echo $b
                c=$(echo $c4 | awk '{print $1}')
                againcommand=$(echo $c | tr -d '/')
                echo "$againcommand"
                abc=$againcommand$b
                echo $abc
                bde=`touch -t $abc "newing.txt"`
                echo $bde




        done
done < $aa
```

Any answers would be helpful!

Comment: Re: "So for this I have to create a script"... where's the script, or what have you tried?

Comment: I just found how to change the modification time of the file..  with the #touch -t command. But I don't know how to create the script to search for the directory and files inside..

Comment: I would recommend attempting to create the script and searching this site for similar question(s); including what you've tried in your question goes a long way,  otherwise it can appear like a request for free coding services essentially.

Comment: What do you mean by "if they are the same"? Just concatenate the directory name and filename, and change the modification time of that file. You don't need to "match" anything.

Comment: @Barmar I think I got you, but the thing is I don't know how to match the names from the List.txt, because all the file name which I have on that list already on the Linux, just need to change the time

Comment: YOu don't need to match anything. Just create a filename like `filename=$dir/$file` then set timestamp of `$filename`.

Comment: No, there is nothing here about creating new files. I have the files after migration, thousands of files, I mean now they exist on my Linux machine, just the time was set incorrect after migration. And I have to change it back as it was before, before I mean when it was modified back in 1990.

Comment: You're almost there with your processing being driven by `list.txt`. Just change to the directory that has the files in it and run your process. It will find each file as the list is processed and then issue the `touch` command. (Or that is how I would do it). If you have multiple directories, then you'll have to manage that, but you can run the same script in multiple directories, and `touch` command will fail when the file is not there, but it will work when the correct file is there. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the updating of the file modification times simply using `awk` with its `system` command to invoke `touch -d` to update the file times from field `4` in the comma separated values file. For example:

```
awk -v FS=', ' '{ system("touch -d "$4 " " $1"/"$2) }' inputfile
```

Here `awk` reads each line with the `awk` variable for the *field-separator* set as `FS=', '` (a comma and a space). It then invokes the `system` command calling `touch -d`, providing field `4` as the "date time" timestamp used for updating the file in the directory specified as `$1/$2` (e.g. `dir1/filename1`).

Using your input file as `inputfile` it would be equivalent to calling:

```
touch -d 1995/01/09 10:35 dir1/filename1
touch -d 1994/12/10 05:43 dir2/filename2
touch -d 2005/10/11 14:56 dir3/filename3
```

The quoting within the `system(...)` command is provided to quote the *non-field* portions of the command. For `"touch -d "$4 " " $1"/"$2`, the command is then built using:

- `"touch -d "`  (e.g. `touch -d` and a space)
- $4 (the 4th field)
- `" "` (places a space between the end of the 4th field and beginning of dir/filename)
- `$1` (the 1st field - the dirname)
- `"/"` (the separator between `dirname/filename`)
- `$2` (finally, the filename)

(**note:** you are essentially quoting everything that isn't an `awk` provided field)

You can do the same thing with `chown` and the 5th field to update the file ownership as well.

Comment: This command works great, but it changes the time only in those files which have the same directory name.. How about if they are different? Thank you

Comment: @asel the directory information is provided by the first field in your data file on each line, e.g. `"dir1, filename1, ..."`. This routine (or any routine for that matter) can only change the timestamp for those files named in your `List.txt` file. Now, there are ways to change the modification time on other files to some predefined date/time, but you have to have that `"date/time"`. Generically if you wanted to change all other files to some date/time, you could use the `find` command combined with `-newermt date time`, or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat List.txt |while read z;do if [ -f $(echo $z|cut -d, -f1)/$(echo $z|cut -d, -f2|sed "s/^\s\+//g") ];then echo touch -t $(echo $z|cut -d, -f4|cut -d ' ' -f2|tr -d '/')$(echo $z|cut -d, -f4|cut -d ' ' -f3|tr -d ':') $(echo $z|cut -d, -f1)/$(echo $z|cut -d, -f2|sed "s/^\s\+//g") ;fi;done
```

you can remove the `echo` to execute the command. It will check if the file exists, and if it does, then it will apply the timestamp to it

Sorry, I just can't add the comments yet. So which echo I have to take and put this command instead? Thank you

Comment: While this may work (I didn't verify), it is quite inefficient spawning more than a dozen processes per-line of input including `cut` (invoked 8-times per-iteration), `sed` (invoked 2-times per-iteration) and `tr` (and don't forget the pipes tying `stdout` of the first process to `stdin` of the next). Also, `"cat | ..."` is an unnecessary use of `cat`. You can simply feed the loop with `while read z; do ... done < List.txt` using *redirection* for its intended purpose.

Comment: Great thanks, but what if the directories have different names? Because yours one is changing only when directory names are same and file names as well